# Are there any papers on the neurobiology/ neuroscience of hyper-industriousness?

Tags: neuroscience, personality, neurophysiology

I'm quite intrigued by this topic, and, unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any interesting papers on the subject...More specifically, I'd like to know more about the mechanisms that regulate industriousness, and whether there are any prospects of making people more industrious using drugs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you mean by “hyper-industriousness” exactly. There is some recent evidence to suggest that small amounts of hallucinogenics create a productivity or creativity boost.

https://harmreductionjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12954-019-0333-3

The government experimented with methamphetamines on soldiers but the long term effects are detrimental. Of course, notably so is sending an 18 year old to battle so it difficult to claim the resulting shell shock was only related to one variable.

https://projectknow.com/blog/three-of-the-craziest-government-drug-experiments-ever/

The problem with the benefits of drugs is their curvilinear effectiveness. There is essentially a window of proper dosage that is both difficult to maintain and highly variable.